# How to update a Single File Component's data with its method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm in the process of learning Vue.js and now I'm learning about Single File Component. My objective is to ask user for their location through Geolocation API and then update the page with their latitude and longitude coordinate values. I'm able to get the coords values through console.log, but I can't get the SFC to update itself with the values. I may be missing something here.

**geolocation.vue**

```
<template>
  <p>Your location is: {{ text }}. Is this correct?</p>
</template>

<script>
  console.log('in geolocation.vue');
  let text = "N/A";

  export default {
    name: "geolocation",
    data: function () {
      return {
        text: text,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      findLocation: function() {
      let that = this;
      console.log('in findLocation()');
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
          console.log('CONSOLE: ' + pos.coords.latitude + ', ' + pos.coords.longitude);
          that.text = pos.coords.latitude + ', ' + pos.coords.longitude;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 85%;
  }
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="center-text">
      <h1 class="site-title">{{ app_name }}</h1>
      <p>I'm the store page!</p>
      <p>Soon I'll display products according to the inventory at the distribution center(s) in the area.</p>
      <geolocation/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
  import geolocation from './geolocation';

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['app_name'])
    },
    components: {
      geolocation
    },
    mounted: function() {
      geolocation.methods.findLocation();
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  .site-title {
      font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  }
  .center-text {
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the *geolocation.vue*

```
mounted() {
  this.findLocation();
}
```

Remove these lines in *App.vue*

```
mounted: function() {
  geolocation.methods.findLocation();
}
```

Split your component into many child component and it has cycle hooks its self.
When `geolocation` component has been mounted, `findLocation` will be called and the location will be bind into the template.

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thank you!